# Help with distance of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K$ and $L$ be non-empty compact sets, and define $d=$inf$\{|x-y|: x \in K$ and $y \in L\}$

1. If $K$ and $L$ are disjoint, show $d>0$ and that $d=|x_0 -y_0|$ for some $x_0 \in K$ and $y_0 \in L$

   - **Proof:** Assume $d \leq 0$.
     Case I: $d<0$
     since $d = |x_0-y_0|, d \nless 0$ which is a contradiction.
     Case II: $d=0$\
     Let $(x_n) \in K$ and $(y_n) \in L$. Since K and L are compact, disjoint sets, it follows that 
     $(x_n) \rightarrow A$ where $A \in K$ and $(y_n) \rightarrow B$ where $B \in L$. Since $K$ and $L$ are disjoint it follows that $A \neq B$. Since $A \neq B$ then $|A-B| \neq 0$ which is a contradiction.
2. Show that it is possible to have $d=0$ if we assume only that the disjoint sets $K$ and $L$ are closed.

   - **Proof:** Let $K= \mathbb{I}^+$ and $L= \mathbb{I}^-$ such that $K,L \in [-1,1]$. It follows that $K \cap L = \emptyset$ and $d(K,L) = 0$.

Comment: Being compact doesn't mean every sequence converges, but that every sequence has a convergent subsequence

Answer (score 1):

Your case two should look more like:

$d=0$ means that for every $\epsilon$ there exists $x\in K$ and $y\in L$ such that $|x-y|<\epsilon$. Define $\epsilon_n = 1/n$. Define a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n$ is within $\epsilon_n$ of an element in $L$. Then, by compactness, $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence that converges to a limit $x$ in $K$. This $x$ must satisfy $|x-y|<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$ and for some $y$ in $L$. Thus $x = y \in L$ by the $\epsilon$ principle, a contradiction.